# Linking with a different .so file in linux

Tags: linux, build-process

I'm trying to compile a piece of software which has the standard build process e.g.

```
configure
make
make install
```

The software requires a library e.g. libreq.so which is installed in /usr/local/lib. However, my problem is I'd like to build the software and link it with a different version of the same library (i have the source for the library as well) that I've installed in /home/user/mylibs.

My question is, how do I compile and link the software against the library in /home/user/mylibs rather than the one in /usr/local/lib

I tried setting "LD_LIBRARY_PATH" to include /home/user/mylibs but that didn't work.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you have an `autoconf` configure script, use:

```
CPPFLAGS=-I/home/user/include LDFLAGS=-L/home/user/mylibs ./configure ...
```

This adds the nominated directory to the list of directories searched for headers (usually necessary when you're using a library), and adds the other nominated directory to the list searched for actual libraries.

I use this all the time - on my work machine, `/usr/local` is 'maintained' by MIS and contains obsolete code 99.9% of the time (and is NFS-mounted, read-only), so I struggle to avoid using it at all and maintain my own, more nearly current, versions of the software under `/usr/gnu`.  It works for me.

Answer (score 2):

Try using [LD_PRELOAD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_linker#LD_PRELOAD) set to your actual file.

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't seem to override the /usr/local/lib version in the build process, are there some arguments I can pass to configure to tell it to use a library in a specific location?

Answer (score 0):

LD_LIBRARY_PATH is for finding the dynamic link libraries at runtime. At compiling you should add -L parameters to gcc/g++ to specify in which directory the *.so files are. You also need to add the library name with -l<NAME> (where the library is libNAME.so).

Important! For linking you not only need the libNAME.so file but a libNAME.a is needed too.

When you run the application, don't forget to add the dir to the LD_LIBRARY_PATH.

Comment: @ Important! For linking you not only need the libNAME.so file but a libNAME.a is needed too. -> aren't you talking about windows (.dll + .lib)? .a is static library and isn't needed at all.

Answer (score 0):

When you added the `/home/user/mylibs` to the LD_LIBRARY_PATH did you add it to the front or end of the existing paths? The tokens are searched in-order so you will want yours to appear first in the list.

Also, many standard build environments that use `configure` will allow you to specify an exact library for each required piece. You will have to run `./configure --help` but you should see something like `--using-BLAH-lib=/path/to/your/library` or similar.