# Tint2 Compilation

Tags: c, gcc, dependencies, compilation, autoconf

I'm on a network where I don't have root access, so everything I install is under a prefix ~/bin (actually referenced by its full path).
So I have openbox working fine, which is what I'm using to send this from. Imlib2 I do `./configure --prefix=~/bin; make; make install`.
Then I run from the tint2 source directory

```
IMLIB2_CFLAGS=-i~/bin/include/Imlib2.h *only typoed here
export IMLIB2_CFLAGS
IMLIB2_LIBS=-l~/bin/lib/libImlib2.a
export IMLIB2_LIBS
./configure --prefix=~/bin
```

which leaves me with this charming message

```
checking for IMLIB2... yes
checking for imlib_context_set_display in -lImlib2... no
configure: error: Imlib2 must be built with X support
```

Edit:

So Imlib2 is now compiled --with-x and installed to the location I'm referencing. I am still receiving an identical error message.

Answer (score 1):

> I'm guessing it's because I don't know what the flags are for the initial configure of imlib2?

Probably, yes.  `./configure --help` will usually give you advice on what to do (i.e., how to pass the correct information to the configure script; but you'll need to find out what that information is a la imlib2).

Comment: Imlib2 needed to be run as ./configure --with-x --prefix=~/bin. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If your Q is accurate, you should fix the spelling of CLFAGS in the first line.

More generally, you could use:

```
CPPFLAGS=-I~/bin/include LDFLAGS=-L~/bin/lib ./configure ...
```

However, as the accepted answer suggests, there is often a direct way to specify the location of pre-requisite software packages.

See also: [Linking with a different .so file in Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1405074/linking-with-a-different-so-file-in-linux/1405105#1405105).